# Android / Java Json Objects count

Tags: java, android, json

I'm parsing in android a json api which looks like this:

```
 [
   {
     "id":70,
     "number_of_devices":12,
    },
    {
      "id":71,
      "number_of_devices":5,
    }
   ]
```

Now I want to get the total count of all devices and display it inside a textview and the total count of all id's and display this inside another textview.
Can any one give me an example how to do this, or any tutorial about this ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The different tasks are covered in existing documentation, guides, tutorials, and even other SO questions - SO is not a tutorial recommendation service. Start with *parsing* the JSON into an appropriate data-structure (search for "android parse JSON"). Then it's just a matter of taking *that* data (Java objects, not the original JSON) and connecting it to the appropriate View.

Comment: I've already parsed that Json Api. I just need a total int of all Objects named id and number_of_devices thats all

Comment: Good. Then we *don't need to see the JSON or tag* - otherwise we'll end  up with responses saying how to parse JSON. Now, since you have the JSON parsed, *what Java Objects* (and containers for such) do you have? How can those be manipulated to answer the queries?

Comment: @user2761273 see my edited answer and tell me if it is what you need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've got your JSON in a String (myString):

```
JSONArray mArray = new JSONArray(myString);
int id_count = 0;
int devices_count = 0;
int tmp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<mArray.length(); i++) {
    try {
        tmp = mArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
        id_count = id_count + 1;
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // If id doesn't exist, this exception is thrown
    }  
    try {
        tmp = mArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("number_of_devices");
        devices_count = devices_count + 1;
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // If number_of_devices doesn't exist, this exception is thrown
    }    
}

myTextView1.text = String.ValueOf(id_count);
myTextView2.text = String.ValueOf(devices_count);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you can try save json into String called jsonString

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString );

int count = jsonArray.length();
```

For adding to text view.

```
for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length();i++) {
       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

       TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

       tv.setText(jsonObject.getString("your_key"));
}
```

Comment: I'll try out, plz wait